# PHP Image Uploader -- Truncated array post processing?

Tags: php, arrays

Alright, I'm building a basic image uploader for some clients and I'm running into some kind of bug and I'm tearing my hair out.

After I get the $_FILES array I do a little processing to make it easier to parse the images but post processing my values are truncated.

Here's the relevant PHP:

```
function organizeFilesArray(&$file_post) {

    $file_array = array();
    $file_count = count($file_post['name']);
    $file_keys = array_keys($file_post);

    for ($i=0; $i<$file_count; $i++) {
        foreach ($file_keys as $key) {
            $file_array[$i][$key] = $file_post[$key][$i];
            echo "$file_array[$i][$key]";
            echo " ... ";
            echo "$file_post[$key][$i]    ";
        }
        echo "$file_count ";

    }

    return $file_array;
}

if(isset($_POST)){
    $destinationDirectory = '/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/image_upload/uploads/';

    //check if _FILES array is empty or if the file was uploaded via POST
    if(!isset($_FILES['ImageFile']) || !is_uploaded_file($_FILES['ImageFile']['tmp_name'])){
        die('Something went wrong with Upload!');
    }

    //clean up the array so I can handle it simply
    //$imageArray = organizeFilesArray($_FILES['ImageFile']);
    $file_array = organizeFilesArray($_FILES['ImageFile']);
    echo" array size pp: " . sizeof($file_array);
    foreach($file_array as $file){
        //random number to be added after image name
        $randomNumber   = rand(0, 9999999999);

        //access these values by using their index position
        //$imageName  = str_replace(' ','-',strtolower($file['name']));
        $imageName  = $file['name']; //get file name
        $imageSize  = $file['size']; // Obtain original image size
        $tempSrc    = $file['tmp_name']; // Tmp name of image file stored in PHP tmp folder
        $imageType  = $file['type']; //Obtain file type, returns "image/png", image/jpeg, text/plain etc.

        echo "This is the type before we try: " . $file['type'];
        echo "This is the name before we try: " . $file['name'];
        echo "This is the size before we try: " . $file['size'];
        //make sure filetype is supported
        switch(strtolower($imageType)){
            case 'image/png':
                $createdImage =  imagecreatefrompng($file['tmp_name']);
                break;
            case 'image/gif':
                $createdImage =  imagecreatefromgif($file['tmp_name']);
                break;
            case 'image/jpeg':
            case 'image/pjpeg':
                $createdImage = imagecreatefromjpeg($file['tmp_name']);
                break;
            default:
                die('Unsupported File!:'.$imageType); //output error and exit
        }
```

Sorry for all the echo statements in there, trying to figure out what's going on. When trying to upload something I get this (from Firebug): 
[image]

So.. after processing, everything in my array is being truncated to the first character it seems like? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you might be breaking up just one of your uploaded files.

Try changing:

```
$file_array = organizeFilesArray($_FILES['ImageFile']);
```

to just

```
$file_array = organizeFilesArray($_FILES);
```

Comment: beside the fact that I ended up having to completely re-write the function, haha, this was part of the issue! thanks!